# How to pass extra parameter to Tapped Event?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I create 10 TextBlock programmatically in Windows phone app 8.1
Now i want to add Tapped event to each TextBlock and pass extra parameter to it so i can find which TextBlock is tapped

I uses this code to create TextBlock with Tapped event:

```
for (int i=1;i<11;i++)
{
    TextBlock txtName = new TextBlock();
    txtName.Tapped += TxtName_Tapped;
}

private void TxtName_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Something
}
```

How can i pass extra parameter?

Comment: can you not do `((TextBlock)sender).Name` to see which one was tapped?

Comment: I don't know how to use this. please tell me how

Comment: Was about to convert to answer but one has been provided with the same idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Ric suggested you can always do:

```
 private void TxtName_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        clickedElementName = ((TextBlock)sender).Name ;
        if(clickedElementName == "element1")
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: this will not work as Name property has never been assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending an extra parameter, you can use the `sender` parameter to identify the `TextBlock`.

```
for (int i=1;i<11;i++)
{
    TextBlock txtName = new TextBlock();
    txtName.Name = i.ToString();
    txtName.Tapped += TxtName_Tapped;
}

private void TxtName_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBlock textBlock = sender as TextBlock;
    switch(textBlock.Name)
    {    
         // list possible cases
         case "1":
         {
             // do something 
         }
    }
}
```

maybe you don't even need a switch statement as I do not know the exact requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, very easy solution is to use `Tag` property:

```
for (int i=1;i<11;i++)
{
    TextBlock txtName = new TextBlock();
    txtName.Tag = i;
    txtName.Tapped += TxtName_Tapped;
}
```

and:

```
private void TxtName_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int tag = ((TextBlock)sender).Tag;
    //do something
}
```